# kernel module not getting registered with kernel when built as module, though if built-in it works

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

This is my first time working with kernel modules at core. I am trying to run a sensor BMC150 for which the kernel already has an IIO-framework driver : 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/magnetometer

I can see this :

```
static const struct of_device_id bmc150_magn_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "bosch,bmc150_magn" },
    { .compatible = "bosch,bmc156_magn" },
    { .compatible = "bosch,bmm150_magn" },
    { }
};
```

So I created my device tree node like this :

```
 magn@13 {
             compatible = "bosch,bmc150_magn";
             reg = <0x13>;
             status = "ok";
         };
```

Now if I have built the module as built-in, I can see the driver under `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers` and the probe happens and I can see the device under `/sys/bus/iio/devices` and everything works fine and I am able to get the readings from the sensor.

However, if I would have build the module as 'M' (not built-in), I do not see the module under `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers` and also no IIO devices get generated. Seems like the kernel does not know about the driver.
What is the problem here ? (I am using busybox rootfs and I used `make modules_install` to install the modules to the rootfs. If I do "modprobe  the driver loads and everything works fine)

i read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580862/device-tree-mismatch-probe-never-called) SO post that if a module has other modules yet-to-be loaded as dependencies then these problems may happen. Is this the issue, am not sure. Please guide.

Comment: Does everything runs fine when you manually modprobe the driver?

Comment: I think you need to do a depmod - a on the target board and reboot the board. See if it works out. This answer here explains automatic loading of modules https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43699/debian-does-not-detect-serial-pci-card-after-reboot/43723#43723

Comment: @R.k.Lohana : Yes after manually doing modprobe, it works fine.

Comment: I also tried creating `/etc/modules-load.d/mymodules.conf` file.

Comment: Have you tried running depmod -a on board and reboot?

Comment: Everywhere I see that `/etc/modules-load.d/<file>.conf` accompanies systemd and since I am using busybox rootfs, I do not have systemd. Not sure if this is the problem (assuming I really need to use modules-load.d approach)

Comment: Seems like I need to use init script only : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396542/buildroot-how-to-load-modules-automatically

Comment: Check the script from Buildroot distribution. It probes all modules for found devices.

Comment: You can add cold/hot-plugging support with udev or busybox's mdev (You can have udev without the rest of systemd.) You may also need to configure UEVENT support in busybox. As long as the modules.alias file has been generated, this should cause the module to be loaded automatically.